# Relationship of geometric multiplicity with eigenvalue dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let T : V → V and S : V → V be linear transformations. Suppose v has 
an eigenvector of T with corresponding eigenvalue λ.
an eigenvector of S with corresponding eigenvalue µ.

Show that Geometric multiplicity µλ ≥ dim(Eλ ∩ Eµ).

So here I know that geometric multiplicity must be at least 1 and less than algebraic multiplicity but can anyone show me how do I use that if i need to at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "geometric multiplicity $\mu\lambda$".  Do you compose $S$ with $T$, perhaps?

Comment: Then yes any vector in the intersection will apparently be an eigenvector of the composition.